# Python: using a loop to do the same with several variables

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have 30 variables with the pattern `aod7039, aod7040, ...., aod7068`. 
I want to do the same operation (i.e. calculate the mean over an axis) for all these variables and overwrite the original variables.
Up to now I wrote 30 times the same line, and wondered if there isn't maybe an shorter and easier way to do this?
I am gradeful for every idea!

Comment: You could combine all variable in a dictionary, which is iterable.

Comment: you could also use `eval` but keep that in mind **eval is evil**

Comment: Take a step back. Why do you have 30 similar variables? Is this not a misrepresentation of an array?

Comment: The number at the end of 'aod' is the year, and I want to do a time series over the 30 years. And unfortunately, there are 30 files, so I need to read in each variable separately from each file and then modify them a bit.

Comment: No you don't; you need to read in each file and then append to the same list or dict. No need for 39 variables.

Comment: Note that we're not saying you shouldn't have 30 values; we're saying you should organize them as a group. That starts where you build the list of file names to read from, probably.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Could figure it out with your ideas! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use 30 variables, use a list `aod[]`
Secondly, use

```
for i in range(7039, 7069):
    aod[i] = yourFunction(aod[i])
```

to override existing list

Answer (score 2):

This will get you all values of variables that start with `'aod'`

```
values = [v for k,v in globals() if k.startswith('aod')]
```

But having 30 variables smells bad.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you just want to iterate over those variables?

If so you could keep references on some list/dictionary and then iterate/update this way.

```
List = []
List.append(aod7039)
for item in List:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have 30 variables with the pattern aod7039, aod7040, ...., aod7068

Then you have a design problem - you should have a `list` or `dict` instead. Replace all those variables with either a `list` or `dict` (or `collections.OrderedDict` if you need key access while preserving insertion order) and then it's only a matter of iterating over your container, ie

```
# with a list:
for index, item in enumerate(yourlist):
    yourlist[index] = do_something_with(item)

# with a dict or OrderedDict:
for key, item in enumerate(yourdict):
    yourdic[key] = do_something_with(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

store your 30 variables in a list and use map to tackle it without any loop:

```
varlist=[aod7039, aod7040, ...., aod7068]
result=list(map(yourfunction, varlist))
```